# Error: Upgrade Fragment version to at least 1.3.0. [InvalidFragmentVersionForActivityResult]

Tags: java, android

I have the following login with google code in java android.

```
private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        someActivityResultLauncher.launch(signInIntent);
}

ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(result.getData());
                    handleSignInResult(task);
                }
            }
        }
);
```

And I get this linting error. App does run on device. But I would like to fix this issue.

```
/home/runner/work/etu-android/etu-android/app/src/main/java/com/encycode/etus/Login.java:151: Error: Upgrade Fragment version to at least 1.3.0. [InvalidFragmentVersionForActivityResult]
    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
                                                                ^

   Explanation for issues of type "InvalidFragmentVersionForActivityResult":
   In order to use the ActivityResult APIs you must upgrade your              
     Fragment version to 1.3.0. Previous versions of FragmentActivity         
          failed to call super.onRequestPermissionsResult() and used invalid
   request codes
```

I am using following library version

```
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.1"
```

Comment: How did you fix this false positive lint error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/182388985) which is already fixed for the next version. You can either wait for that release to come out or suppress the warning.

**Edit**: [Fragment 1.3.2](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.3.2) has been released and states:

> Fragment now depends on [Activity 1.2.2](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity#1.2.2), fixing an issue with Activity’s `InvalidFragmentVersionForActivityResult` lint check when using Fragment 1.3.1 or higher.

So you should upgrade to Fragment 1.3.2.

Comment: I am still getting lint error, this is a bit old project written in Java and I already added `androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.3.0-alpha07` and using `androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.3` working with AS Arctic Fox Canary 15

Comment: Also get this error for `androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.6` with Arctix Fox.

Comment: @CoolMind - you should [file an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=527362) with a project that reproduces your problem.

Comment: It wasn't working for me for 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.6' also but it started working after I added  'androidx.activity:activity:1.3.0-alpha05' to the implementation list ...

Answer (score 1):

See https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity#version_122_3.

If you use `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1`, add also `import androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.2` or `androidx.activity:activity:1.2.2` to remove this Lint error.

Comment: Fragment 1.3.2 already depends on this version of Activity, you don't need to manually include a dependency on it; you'll get fixes for Activity automatically as part of the transitive dependency.

Comment: @ianhanniballake, if don't add this dependency, Lint won't remove the error.

Comment: That's not how transitive dependencies work. You should [file an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=527362&template=1189829) with a project that reproduces your problem if you're finding that necessary.

Answer (score 1):

in my case i've updated `appcompat` lib to this version and it's resolved :

```
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1"
```